# How to add google reCAPTCHA in the newsletter form in magento?

Tags: magento

How to add google reCAPTCHA with the newsletter in magento to stop receiving newsletter emails in the spam.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 3):

Add the below code in the "form file" under the form tag to resolve your query.

```
<div class="recaptcha" style="overflow:hidden;position:relative;">
   <input type="checkbox" id="recaptcha-verification-1" name="recaptcha-verification-1" value="" class="hide required-entry" style="visibility:hidden;position:absolute;left:-1000000px" />
   <div id="recaptcha-1"></div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       var onloadCallback = function() {
           grecaptcha.render('recaptcha-1', {
               'sitekey': "6Lf9tBcTAAAAAEbCd2XlhPGH3o850Qp9ZMJJ2fr2",
               'theme': "light",
               'callback': function(response) {
                   if (response.length > 0) {
                       $('recaptcha-verification-1').writeAttribute('value', 'checked');
                       $('recaptcha-verification-1').checked = true;
                   }
               }
           });
       };
   </script>
   <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit&hl=en" async defer></script></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the same issue and I made it solved one extension "Google Invisible reCaptcha"

Wait... I changed few modifications in JS code also.

After installing extension set Site key and secret in admin side and open subscription.phtml

```
YOUR-PROJECT/app/design/frontend/YOURTHEME/default/template/newsletter/subscribe.phtml
```

Add code just after Form Tag.

```
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="YOUR-SITE-KEY"></div>
```

In the last of file add this JS Snippet.

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('#recaptcha_response_field').addClass('required-captcha-entry');
    })
    var yourFormValidationObj = new VarienForm('newsletter-validate-details');

    Validation.add('required-captcha-entry', ' ', function(v) {
        return !Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v);
    })
</script>
```

It worked for me. Cheers if it works for you..